# What is the default value for passing a date object as a prop?

Tags: vue.js

In a component you need to specify the props that gets sent to the component stating the type and the default value.

This gives you a "*Invalid default value for prop "dateTime": Props with type Object/Array must use a factory function to return the default value.*" error

```
props: {
    dateTime: {
      type: Date,
      default: new Date()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

there is an issue on the github repo which contains the solution for your issue

look here for the complete explanation https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1032

```
props: {
  arr: {
    type: Date,
    default: function () { return new Date() }
  }
}
```